# How to make that there aren't identical values ​next to each other while randomizing and disable entry in text field?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, random

So I have this Python code that generates pseudorandom numbers with tkinter GUI:

```
def ButClick():
    try:
        MinNum = int (txt1.get())
        MaxNum = int (txt2.get())
        Num = int (txt3.get())
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror("ValueError", "Check if you typed in correct! You can't type in text! Numbers only!")
    else:
        Nums = ''
        if MinNum <= MaxNum:
            i = 0
            while i < Num:
                numOne = randint(MinNum,MaxNum)
                Nums = Nums + " " + str(numOne)
                i += 1
            scr.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n")
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("NumError!", "Your Min Number can't be higher than your Max Number or vice versa!") 
    pass

def remove_text():
    scr.delete(1.0,END)

def confirm():
    answer = askyesno(title='Exit',
                    message='Tired of randomness?') 
    if answer:
        root.destroy() 

root = Tk()
root.title("Hey")
message = Label(root, text= "Welcome to random numbers generator! Developed by Yaroslav Poremsky")
message.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Random is so random :)")

lb1 = Label(root, bg = "green", text = "Min number") 
lb1.grid(
    row = 0, 
    column = 0, 
    pady = 10, 
    padx = 10) 

txt1 = Entry(root, width = 30) 
txt1.grid(
    row = 0,
    column = 1,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

lb2 = Label(root, bg = "orange", text = "Max number")
lb2.grid(
    row = 1,
    column = 0,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

txt2 = Entry(root, width = 30)
txt2.grid(
    row = 1,
    column = 1,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

lb3 = Label(root,  bg = "pink", text = "Number")
lb3.grid(
    row = 2,
    column = 0,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

txt3 = Entry(root, width = 30)
txt3.grid(
    row = 2,
    column = 1,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

but = Button(root, width = 15, height = 2,  bg = "magenta", text = "Generate", command = ButClick) 
but.grid(
    row = 3,
    column = 0,
    columnspan = 2, 
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

but_remove = Button(root, width = 15, height = 2, bg = "crimson", text = "Remove", command = remove_text) 
but_remove.grid(
    row = 3,
    column = 1,
    columnspan = 2,
    pady = 15,
    padx = 20)

but_quit = Button(root, width = 15, height = 2, bg = "violet", text = "Quit", command = confirm) 
but_quit.grid(
    row = 3,
    column = 3,
    columnspan = 2,
    pady = 15,
    padx = 20)
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, bg = "grey", height = 10) 
scr.grid(
    row = 4,
    column = 0,
    columnspan = 2,
    pady = 10,
    padx = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

1. The problem is, when I enter the Min number of 0, Max number of 1 and Number of 12, sometimes identical values stand next to each other(Picture 1)
   [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMZ9H.png)
   How can I make that there aren't identical values ​​next to each other while randomizing?
2. The second thing is, I can type in this box(Picture 2)
   [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j38nA.png)
   How can I disable entry in this field?

I've seen that it is possible to disable entry via creating a button, but can I make it without creating it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1, simply save the last number and compare with current number, if they are the same, discard it and generate another one.

For question 2, simply disable the text box initially.  Enable it before inserting text and disable it back after.

```py
def ButClick():
    try:
        MinNum = int (txt1.get())
        MaxNum = int (txt2.get())
        Num = int (txt3.get())
    except ValueError:
        messagebox.showerror("ValueError", "Check if you typed in correct! You can't type in text! Numbers only!")
    else:
        Nums = ''
        if MinNum <= MaxNum:
            last = MinNum - 1  # set the initial last number
            i = 0
            while i < Num:
                numOne = randint(MinNum,MaxNum)
                if numOne != last:
                    # number is not the same as the last one
                    # so accept it
                    Nums = Nums + " " + str(numOne)
                    i += 1
                    # save current number as last one
                    last = numOne
            scr.config(state="normal")  # enable the text box
            scr.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n")
            scr.see("end")
            scr.config(state="disabled") # disable the text box
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("NumError!", "Your Min Number can't be higher than your Max Number or vice versa!")

def remove_text():
    scr.config(state="normal")
    scr.delete(1.0,END)
    scr.config(state="disabled")
...
scr = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, bg = "grey", height = 10, state="disabled") # initially disabled
...
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but for some reason my "Remove" button stopped working after this. What can be the cause?

Comment: You need to enable the text box before deleting the content and then disable it back.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite get it. Do you mean I just need to change the state from "normal" to "disabled" in scr.config?

Comment: @Poremich Answer updated.  Basically it is the same as when inserting text into the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `Entry` to prevent interaction by using `txt1.config(state='disabled')`. The other problem of consecutive identical numbers is trickier. In the case where you only have two options, `0` and `1`, disallowing repeated numbers would then *always* generate a sequence of alternating `0`s and `1`s (not very random after all!).

You could conceivably fix this by adding another loop to continue generating random numbers until a "new" number is generated, but this can slow things down needlessly if the RNG keeps coming up with consecutive numbers by chance.

```
# NOT RECOMMENDED
while i < Num:
    # loop until 'numOne' is different from the last number in the 'Nums' string
    while (numOne := randint(MinNum,MaxNum)) == int(Nums[-1])
        pass
    Nums = Nums + " " + str(numOne)
    i += 1
```

Another option is to simply add or subtract from `numOne` if it's identical to the previous number - you'll just have to check if it's still between `MinNum` and `MaxNum`

```
while i < Num:
    numOne = randint(MinNum, MaxNum)
    # if the new number matches the previous number...
    if numOne == int(Nums[-1]):  
        if numOne - 1 > MinNum:
            numOne -= 1
        elif numOne + 1 < MaxNum:
            numOne += 1
    Nums = Nums + " " + str(NumOne)
    i += 1
```

This may not be the best approach either, as it's not truly random, but you get the idea. And again, in the case where only two numbers are allowed (regardless of what they are) you will end up with a sequence of alternating numbers.

A better approach is shown in [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-generate-non-repeating-random-numbers-in-Python)